# Iota full node server & cloudflare warp

Tags: iri-node, iota-network

I have been wondering if anyone thought of using [cloudflare warp](https://www.cloudflare.com/products/cloudflare-warp/) on a public full node to load balance it.

Is this feasible? Or better yet, is this of any real use?

Comment: Cloudflare Warp offers origin protection, not load balancing.

Comment: @Helmar it says it does both